# How to display the scope in html from a custom directive in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angular js.

How can I display the values of `e.width` and `e.height` in HTML ? Can I use the scope in here?

```
    .directive( "cropping", [function ($scope) {
  return {
      restrict: "A",
      link    : function ( $scope, $el, $attr ) {
          $attr.$observe( "src", function ( src ) {
                      jQuery( '#cropImage' ).cropper('destroy');
                      jQuery( '#cropImage' ).cropper( {
                          viewMode        : 0,
                          zoomable        : false,
                          preview: ".extra-preview",
                          dragMode        : 'crop',
                          guides          : true,
                          highlight       : true,
                          cropBoxMovable  : true,
                          cropBoxResizable: true,
                          crop            : function ( e ) {
                              // Output the result data for cropping image.
                              console.log( e.width );
                              console.log( e.height );

                          }
                      } );
          } );
      }
  }
} ] );
```

Comment: I think you can try to do it with this wrapper
https://github.com/koorgoo/ngCropper

Comment: I already used this, but it has a little problem. When you load an image after the first one the Cropper doesn't initialize...

Comment: Maybe try something like init on each load of an image, if you use jQuery then it probably don't see changes from Angular, and maybe you need some trigger to re-initialize it?

Answer (score 0):

using below code you will get HTML height and width directly.

```
console.log( e[0].offsetHeight);
console.log( e[0].offsetWidth);
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question.